# How could i make this deep-copy / iterating dictionary work, and how could i make it cleaner?

Tags: c#, dictionary

i know my question isn't really detailled, by i didn't know how to ask it, since i don't really how to explain my issue without writting many lines. Anyway, here is my actual code

```
var numberOfItemInTempDict = 0;

Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, List<dynamic>>> tempDict = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, List<dynamic>>>();

foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, List<dynamic>>> kvp in alertSortedByCompanyAndType.ToList())
{
     // We iterate through all the companies id
     foreach (var kvp2 in kvp.Value)
     {
         // We iterate through all array of type in one company
         foreach (var item in kvp2.Value)
         {
              // We iterate through all the data for one array of type in one company
              if (!tempDict.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
              {
                   tempDict.Add(kvp.Key, new Dictionary<string, List<dynamic>>());
              }

              if (!tempDict[kvp.Key].ContainsKey(kvp2.Key))
              {
                   tempDict[kvp.Key].Add(kvp2.Key, new List<dynamic>());
              }

              // We add the item to the tempDictionary
              tempDict[kvp.Key][kvp2.Key].Add(item);

              // And after adding it, we delete it from the original dictionary
              alertSortedByCompanyAndType[kvp.Key][kvp2.Key].Remove(item);

              numberOfItemInTempDict++;

              if (numberOfItemInTempDict >= 250)
              {
                    break;
              }
          }

          if (numberOfItemInTempDict >= 250)
          {
                break;
          }
      }
      if (numberOfItemInTempDict >= 250)
      {
          break;
      }
}
```

The problem here seems to be that i'm deleting items from alertSortedByCompanyAndType dictionary, but i'm iterating to it as well, so there is a InvalidOperationException since the collection was modified during iteration.

But, i also saw somewhere that by doing a ToList(), it's recreating alertSortedByCompanyAndType, and then, you can do whatever you want with the original dict since the ToList() will be our iterated dictionary. I could have missinterpreted it as well, and that's probably the case.

**(If you have any improvements for my code, feel free to tell me or explain what i do wrong, i'm quite new, the following text is mandatory for the question answer)**

For the few if at the end of each foreach, it's because i want it to iterate only 250 times, but there could be like 250 items for one company, or either 1 item for 250 company, or whatever, maybe i could just do a function to then just return instead of doing ugly if statement like i do.

For the tempDict that i used above, it's because both dictionary can be populated asynchronously, and the first dictionary could contain like 2000 items, but i want the tempDict to only have 250 of them, so i can pass the tempDict to another function that is after that.

And for the dynamic keyword for the list, it contains items that can be from 9 different classes (for now at least) that i receive in json from another program, so i deserialize them, using dynamic keyword since i don't really need to access to all the data in it, only part of it, i use the class to then register alerts to Amazon SQS.

Comment: Any particular reason you are removing the `item` from that list? That still has to be done, does it? Does it have to be in a foreach or you are fine with having any other method? What is the `alertSortByCompanyAndType` (and why make it a `ToList()`)

Comment: I'm removing it so that i don't iterate through it on the new execution of those many foreach, i could just do another many foreach statements to just delete the item that i just added in tempDict, but i though it would kinda "make sense" do delete it as soon as we add it to tempDict, but it doesn't work like that so maybe i'll change that. The alertSortByCompanyAndType is the same type as tempDict (that is, a Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, List<dynamic>>>), and i saw somewhere that doing a ToList was a way to "modify and iterate through it" in one foreach statements

Comment: Instead of doing like, a foreach that add items to a dictionary, and then, create a variable List that store all items that were added, and then doing another foreach loop that will delete items based on that list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to split the copying and deleting. Put the items you want to remove in a list instead of removing them right away. After you are done remove them afterwards from the actual dictionary.

Something like this (pseudocode, untestet)

```
List<ValueTuple<string, string, object>> toBeDeleted = new List...; //asuming kvp.Key and kvp2.Key are strings and the item is object, use your actuall types
....
//instead of alertSortedByCompanyAndType[kvp.Key][kvp2.Key].Remove(item);
toBeDeleted.Add((kvp.Key,kvp2.Key,item))
....
//after the foreach nests
foreach( var d  in toBeDeleted)
alertSortedByCompanyAndType[d.Item1][d.Item2].Remove(d.Item3);
```

Comment: I though something that is quite different, didn't know other way of doing like, one foreach nest that iterate tempDict and add item, and one foreach nest that iterate to alertSortedByCompanyAndType and delete, but with the Tuple it seems that i don't need the second foreach nest, since all keys will be in this tuple, seems far better than what i was thinking to do.

Comment: I'm glab my answer gave you a few pointers. Let us know if it worked out for you. Feel free to ask follow up questions.

Comment: Works perfectly, another question that is not prioritary, what could i do about my multiple if at the end of foreach for the tempDict iteration ? seems really ugly, but don't really know how to do better. I though about doing a function, and just return at the first if in the last foreach statement, but if you have another idea, why not

Comment: You could (but shouldn't) use a goto. Using goto will usually bring you no joy except in special few occasions.
Using a function is way cleaner. Generally speaking breaking down your code in small functions is good practice and will help you organize your code

Comment: Yeah i was warned for the goto, i though about it but i never used it, i will definitely make a function then. Thanks you !